# can not access directory without specify index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make my app root directory can be accessed without specify index.php like

```
www.domainname.com/dev/
```

My .htaccess now is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my localhost it works, but in my hosting, when i access, it says "directory access is forbidden"
What should i change?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will solve the problem.

Add something like this in your .htaccess file at root directory:

```
DirectoryIndex  index.php  index.html
```

The first file found, from left to right, will be loaded by default. You can add more files or remove *index.html* as appropriate. This is just an example.